# NGINX Permissions: 'sudo nginx' vs 'sudo service nginx start'

Tags: centos, nginx, ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm doing a capistrano Setup here with nginx 1.6.2 and Unicorn.
But Under my current setup nginx doesn't create the server i have written in con file.
Im sure its a permission error for my user's directory as thats where the conf files are located under two rails app dir.

My nginx file is as below:

```
user  mjp nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

   keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` is empty.

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/;` directory contains 2 symlinks:

```
[mjp@centos nginx]$ ll sites-enabled/
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 61 Jan  5 06:58 mjp-portal_production -> /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_production/shared/config/nginx.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 58 Jan  3 21:03 mjp-portal_staging -> /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/shared/config/nginx.conf
```

All Permission leading unto those con files:

```
[mjp@centos ~]$ ll
total 4
drwxrwxr-x. 4 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  5 06:58 apps

[mjp@centos ~]$ ll apps/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 5 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  5 07:27 mjp-portal_production
drwxrwxr-x. 5 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  3 21:11 mjp-portal_staging


[mjp@centos ~]$ ll apps/mjp-portal_staging/
total 16
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mjp nginx   57 Jan  3 21:11 current -> /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/releases/20150103210756
drwxrwxr-x. 4 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  3 21:07 releases
drwxrwxr-x. 7 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  3 21:04 repo
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mjp nginx   71 Jan  3 21:11 revisions.log
drwxrwxr-x. 9 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  3 21:05 shared


[mjp@centos ~]$ ll apps/mjp-portal_staging/shared/
total 28
drwxrwxr-x. 2 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  3 21:10 bin
drwxrwxr-x. 3 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  3 21:05 bundle
drwxrwxr-x. 2 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  5 07:46 config
drwxrwxr-x. 2 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  3 21:11 log
drwxrwxr-x. 3 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  3 21:04 public
drwxrwxr-x. 5 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  3 21:04 tmp
drwxrwxr-x. 3 mjp nginx 4096 Jan  3 21:04 vendor

[mjp@centos ~]$ ll apps/mjp-portal_staging/shared/config/
total 24
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mjp nginx  136 Jan  3 21:03 database.example.yml
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mjp nginx  155 Jan  3 21:06 database.yml
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mjp nginx  188 Jan  3 21:03 log_rotation
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mjp nginx  814 Jan  5 07:46 nginx.conf
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mjp nginx 1996 Jan  3 21:03 unicorn_init.sh
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mjp nginx 1327 Jan  3 21:03 unicorn.rb
```

`mjp-portal_production -> /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_production/shared/config/nginx.conf`:

```
upstream unicorn1 {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_production.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server
{
  server_name 185.48.117.98;
  listen 8080 default;
  root /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_production/current/public;

  #access_log /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_production/shared/log/nginx_access.log;
  #error_log  /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_production/shared/log/nginx_error.log;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn1;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

`mjp-portal_staging -> /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/shared/config/nginx.conf`:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server
{
  server_name 185.48.117.98;
  listen 8081 default;
  root /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/current/public;

  #access_log /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/shared/log/nginx_access.log;
  #error_log  /home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/shared/log/nginx_error.log;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Even when i set to run the nginx process ("worker") as `root`. Still nginx can't create the server and start listening to it.

`netstat -anp` doesn't show the ports that are open by nginx. In this case  `port 8080 and port 8081`.

What am i doing wrong.
All the permissions seem to be right.
Am i still missing something?
When i put code for these two symlinks in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/. It does opens those ports although i get`502 bad gateway` which makes me think that its a permission error. on those app directories.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `nginx -t`?

Comment: Its says that configuration ok. And test successful.

Comment: Ok. I got it running. But im still confused.
I usually start nginx with `sudo service nginx start`
But this time i stopped it. and then just ran `sudo nginx` which runs and i can see that nginx is listening on `8081` and `8080`. But when i try to stop it with `sudo service nginx stop` it says that it doesn't have permission for `/var/run/nginx.pid` which is weird as i'm doing a sudo on it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so the question is How is `sudo nginx` different than `sudo service nginx start`???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an selinux problem.

When you run `sudo nginx` it starts `nginx` as `unconfined_t`, when you run `sudo service nginx start` it starts nginx as `httpd_t`.

By initially starting with just sudo it creates a bunch of files and initializes its state as `unconfined_t`. For example the pid file will be the wrong context. Thus when using `service nginx stop` to terminate it there is insufficient privileges for `httpd_t` to read files written by the `unconfined_t`.

You should really always start using `service` which will avoid this problem. To correct it you will need to relabel stateful files that exist in the filesystem, for example running `restorecon /var/run/nginx.pid` will correct the incorrect label set on that pid file.

I am not sure if there are any more files that get written out when the service is created which will also need correcting. You can get a list of which files that these might be doing `ausearch -ts recent -m avc`.

Comment: the `ausearch` command needs sudo. And after that it says `<no matches>`


`ls -Z /usr/sbin/nginx` give me `-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_exec_t:s0 /usr/sbin/nginx`

Comment: `ps -eZ | grep nginx` give the following:
`unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 46438 ? 00:00:00 nginx`

Comment: `ls -Z /var/run/nginx.pid` gives:
`-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0 /var/run/nginx.pid`

Comment: How can i rectify this?

Comment: Recent only goes back 10 minutes. You can put a time in from when you know you last ran the sudo command to see if it comes up then.

Answer (score 3):

Some additional information for those who want to extend a little bit knowledge on selinux and to debug issues with selinux:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-se-linux-changes-upgrading-rhel-6-6/

tl;dr

Debug issues with SElinux permissions:

1. set permissive mode ( informs about security breach in audit.log and performs actions )
2. check audit.log ( for centos and probaly all RH familly /var/log/audit/audit.log )
3. apply proper permissions on SElinux or on files

Tool:

```
ausearch -i -m avc
```

will help to read audit.log in human readable format any AVC (SElinux) issue

You can also try to add:
   -ts recent
   -ts today 

to narrow scope of search.